# Javascript won't load using jQuery Mobile with navigation-geolocation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, geolocation

I am having an issue with jQuery Mobile, javascript and get geolocaton.

I am currently using following to get the code to load, when I enter the page:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
```

If the user has set visibility to visible, a div with the ID visible is shown, this I use to call the geolocation the first time:

```
if ($('#visible').length) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sucessHandler, errorHandler);
}
```

After this I call the geolocation every 20th second:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if ($('#visible').length) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sucessHandler);
    }
}, 20000);
```

My issue is, if I leave the page for one of the subpages, and return to this page, these codes won't run again. I have tried the following to load the javascript, instead of pageinit:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){
```

and

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function()
```

I tried loading it in the body of the index as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated =)

Regards, Fred

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you may want to consider replacing `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` with `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition()`. This will call your success or error handler functions each time the device receives a position update, rather than you needing to ping it every 20 seconds to see if it has changed.

With regard to page changing, so long as you’re using a multi-page template, then the handler function should get called while navigating to and from any sub-pages.

[Here’s a JS fiddle illustrating this](http://jsfiddle.net/dpa99c/9X4K5/)

Hope this helps!